# NodeList empty on console

Tags: javascript, nodelist

My nodeList showing empty in console when I want to find childnodes of HTML.

Here is my code;

```js
const rootNode=document.getRootNode();
const htmlElementNode = rootNode.childNodes[0];
console.log(htmlElementNode.childNodes);
```

Comment: `childNodes[0]` of `document.getRootNode()` has no children - perhaps you wanted `childNodes[1]` instead - of course, you can access that easier with `document.documentElement` .... note: `document.getRootNode().childNodes[0]` is a `DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE` - such as `<!DOCTYPE html>` - this type of node has no children

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. You just need to use the second index.
Why?
Because the first index is '!DOCTYPE html' which has no children.

```js
const rootNode=document.getRootNode();

<!--works with index 1-->
const htmlElementNode = rootNode.childNodes[1];

console.log(htmlElementNode.childNodes);
```

But, in case there is no '!DOCTYPE html' then your code will fail with index as '1'. So you should have another statement to check for it, like so.

```js
const rootNode=document.getRootNode();

let htmlElementNode = rootNode.childNodes[0];

<!-- we added a check to move to next index, in case we get 0 childnodes -->
if (htmlElementNode.childNodes.length <= 0) {
    htmlElementNode = rootNode.childNodes[1]
}

console.log(htmlElementNode.childNodes);
```